# How to flip buttons in iPad apps

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, uiviewanimation

I have ten small rectangular buttons in my iPad application.

When I touch any button it should undergo flip animation(**fliped by 180 degree**),there is also a button named **rotateAll**, on clicking this all button should flip for 2 seconds and again come to their initial state, how can I achieve this?

Comment: When they flip 180 degrees, is something else on the back or just nothing or the button in reverse?

Comment: another image or text.thanks for ur responce!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a transition from one view to the other to create the flip effect, like this

```
[UIView transitionFromView:buttonViewYouAreFlippingAwayFrom 
                    toView:backgroundViewYouAreFlippingTo
                  duration:0.5 // How long the flip should take
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft |
                           UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    // you could do the reverse here after two seconds 
                    // or maybe something else ...
                  }];
```

By default the from view will be added and the to view will be removed from the super view but if you know that they will flip back you can add the `UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews` to instead have the views only show and hide when they transition.

Flipping all buttons would easiest be done by looping over them all and doing the same transition to them all.

Comment: do i need to add button on the another view ,which having frame equal to the frame of button.                                                          That means, i have to create double custom views of the total no of buttons.one for front view and another for back,is it.

Comment: It depends, you could create the view and set the frame without adding it (and remove the ...ShowHide... option). Then the view will be added for you. The other option is to add the same view as the button and set the frame and set hidden=YES. Then when you keep the ...ShowHide... option the background view will have become visible and the button view will become hidden during the transition.